# how can i import my file.jh in my jhister app

Tags: cmd, jhipster, jdl

when i try to import jhipster-jdl.jh in my app, i have this error :
Could not find jhipster-jdl.jh, make sure the path is correct.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WmOg.png)

Comment: Have you checked file permissions and that filename does not contain hidden characters? You could also run `node -e "const shelljs = require('shelljs'); const res = shelljs.test('-f', 'jhipster-jdl.jh'); console.log(res);"` this is exactly  what jhipster does. If it does print false, then it means it's not a jhipster issue.

Comment: thanks, it prints false.
do you know where i should look ?

Comment: The error message is telling you that it cannot find the file `jhipster-jdl.jh` in the current directory (`C:\Users\Omen\Back\laliste\myApp`). Make sure it's there and has read permissions, or provide the proper path in your command.

Comment: thanks, i found the solution, my file.jh was not well placed

Answer (score 0):

You should use include the path to the file (which normally would go here: src/main/webapp/script)

jhipster import-jdl src/main/webapp/script/test.jh

It is a common mistake!
It is explained in the book: [Full Stack Development with JHipster: Build full stack applications and microservices with Spring Boot and modern JavaScript frameworks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1838824987)

which is really helpful when you start.